# How does Fleksy change the keyboard color without RequestsOpenAccess?

Tags: ios, security, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

There’s a new Fleksy keyboard release for iOS 8 featuring a keyboard extension. The color of the keyboard extension can be changed from the containing Flexy.app without turning on the `RequestsOpenAccess` mode (or “Allow Full Access” in the UI). How is that possible when the containing app and the extension share no container?

(Now that I think about it, this is a huge security question, too. If the containing app can communicate with the keyboard extension, maybe it can also read your keystrokes? I’m not saying that Fleksy does it, just that it should be impossible in principle, unless the extension is granted full access.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see. The app doesn’t communicate with the keyboard through the shared container, it communicates through the sample textfield in the app. When user taps to change the color theme, the app inserts a special string into the textfield, the keyboard notices the string, parses the theme name and stores the setting in its own user defaults.

Comment: Wow, thats pretty clever!

Comment: But how do they ensure that their keyboard is the one that is used to "edit" the special text field?

Comment: I'm assuming their keyboard also sends a message when it's visible. Their onboarding is pretty smart.

Comment: This is a pretty clever trick for messaging between the keyboard and the containing app, which is a big hurdle in the Custom Keyboard API.

Comment: You can communicate back and forth using `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"com.bundleID..."];` without turning on `RequestsOpenAccess` but you can't use your app's bundle ID -- make up something unique.

Comment: Doesn’t work for me, @Jeff. And it should not work, by design, according to the official docs: “If you build a keyboard without network access, the system ensures that keystrokes cannot be sent back to you or anywhere else.”